# What is "a student-loan refinancing form"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is it a form to borrow money again for your post-graduate program (MBA/Master/PhD) or a form to pay back the loan you have borrowed for your university program?

"SoFi's approach is unique. It reviewed the self-reported income on over 60,000 student-loan refinancing forms from January 2014 to December 2017."

Source:http://www.businessinsider.com/business-school-highest-salary-ranking-sofi-2018-3#1-university-of-pennsylvania-224034-20

Comment: What did you find when you looked up "[refinancing](http://www.investorwords.com/4115/refinancing.html "Paying off an existing loan with the proceeds from a new loan, usually of the same size, and using the same property as collateral.")" in the dictionary?

Comment: The phrase is generic; **student loan** could include loans for undergraduate and graduate education.  It is a form used to apply for a new loan to replace an older loan or multiple older ones, with terms that are better in some way, such as a lower interest rate and/or more flexible payback terms that allow for a hiatus if you should become unemployed.